# How to pass data I fetched and mapped in react functional component to react modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, fetch, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to update specific objects with fetch PUT.
In the main component I first map through my data that I got with fetch GET and display the data.
Then, onClick, I open a modal, to which I would like to pass the individual object on which the click happened.
The modal only gets the last element's data from the map.

```js
datas.books.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <CardDiv key={v4()} id={data.id}>
              <h3>{data.Title}</h3>
              <h4>by {data.Author}</h4>
              <p>Read: {data.Read && `\u2713`}</p>
              <UpdateModal
                openState={openState}
                setOpenState={setOpenState}
                bookId={data.id}
                setRender={setRender}
                render={render}
                title={data.Title}
                author={data.Author}
                read={data.Read}></UpdateModal>
              <button onClick={() => setOpenState(!openState)}>Edit</button>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setDeleteUrl(`http://localhost:9000/book/del/${data.id}`);
                }}>
                Delete
              </button>
            </CardDiv>
          );
        })
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you'll have as many `Modal` components as you have items. You might want to go to a slightly different architecture and render the `Modal` only once, outside the loop. I'll formulate this into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll have as many `Modal` components as you have items. You might want to go to a slightly different architecture and render the `Modal` only once, outside the loop.

You could potentially have a stateful variable called `selectedId` in which you can store the `id` of the book that you'll be updating.

The following might not work *perfectly*, but it should get you pretty close.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

  const selectedBook = data.books.find((id) => id === selectedId);

  return (
    <>
      <UpdateModal
        openState={selectedId !== undefined}
        setOpenState={() => setSelectedId(undefined)}
        bookId={selectedId}
        setRender={setRender}
        render={render}
        title={selectedBook.Title}
        author={selectedBook.Author}
        read={selectedBook.Read}
      />
      {datas.books.map((data, index) => {
        return (
          <CardDiv key={v4()} id={data.id}>
            <h3>{data.Title}</h3>
            <h4>by {data.Author}</h4>
            <p>Read: {data.Read && `\u2713`}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setSelectedId(data.id)}>Edit</button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setDeleteUrl(`http://localhost:9000/book/del/${data.id}`);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </CardDiv>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, a slight design note: you might just want to pass the whole `book` object to your `Modal` rather than the `id`, `author`, `title`, etc individually. It's just a bit cleaner and reduces the number of props you have to worry about.

Comment: Thank you @Nick, I found my problem - I needed to pass props to my component (React Modal) not just the function that returns the Modal component.

Comment: ... with the spread operator, like: `{...props}`